# Outputting data with NanoStoreInMotion

Tags: rubymotion

I have successfully been able to create a user using NanoStoreInMotion. I can query on it and see the object. What I am having an issue with is outputting data. For example:

User model:

```
class User < NanoStore::Model
  :first_name => "Jason"
  :last_name => "Beam"

  user = User.find(:first_name => "Jason")
  #This returns the object [#<User:0xab96ab0>]
end
```

With ruby, normally to call on a specific field I would just do user.first_name. This throws an error, "undefined method 'first_name' for [#]:Array (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly find returns an Array so you need to do something like user[0].first_name

Based on my experience I would advise against NanoStoreInMotion. I wouldn't exclude my own inability to use it correctly, but for me it was unreasonably slow (storing thousands of relatively complex objects) and throwing a lot of cryptic errors.

So I moved to [MotionModel](https://github.com/sxross/MotionModel) and I am very happy with it.